# Google Analytics Conversions Way Off

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.12, google-analytics

I'm looking at our Magento store's report on GA under the `Multi-Channel Funnels Overview`, and this `Conversions` number is way off. It's about *9 to 10 times larger* (!) than our actual number of conversions for a given period of time. Am I missing something about this report?

It does report, however, the correct order numbers and amount of dollar amount.

We have GA enabled in Magento admin as you would normally set up. Is this report buggy? Magento's GA script is not easy to edit or examine. (it looks like a code generates the script).

We're using Enterprise 1.12.0.2

Comment: Please tag this for the Magento  release version in question.

Comment: Is Enterprise support not an option here?

Comment: ^ Enterprise support won't help you with anything outside of your Magento installation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-channel funnels overview is probably showing you a goal conversion as well as your regular conversions. If you have a goal setup, it will show as a conversion on the overview page. Going into ecommerce specifically will show you the right conversion numbers.

Check your goals to see which ones are enabled. You can filter that information retroactively to see the real numbers from the past as well.

Maybe consider using Google Universal Analytics with Magento as well.